# How do I distribute GIT Objects Across multiple Linux Servers?

Tags: git, github

I have about a 100GB Git to backup, and I have about 15 Linux Servers each with a 10GB storage limit.

How do I distribute the GIT Objects across several of the Servers so that I have enough storage space?

Been really stumped about this, hope someone can help.

Thank you

Comment: That sounds like a seriously bad idea in the first place. If you care about that data, get the right kind of storage to back it up properly. You're setting yourself up for a backup that will be really hard to restore and really easy to lose.

Comment: agreed. A system like that is a massive pain to restore, and the backup is no good if even one of those hard drives fail. You might as well be running RAID0 with 10 hard drives.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fat bandwidth, and enough space on the machine that has that 100GB git backup then you can do something like this (albeit more clunky than a real backup):

```
$ git fsck --full
$ tar cf - .git | split -b 10G - repo.
```

No you should have about 10 files or so named repo.a, repo.b, repo.c and so on, each roughly 10GB that you can copy over to the servers.

Don't forget to save the md5sum of each chunk as well.